# UDID nos in apple account

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I registered a new UDID for an iPad in my Apple developer account. Do I need to create a new provisioning file and certificate? Or do I have to just download old provisioning file and certificate and reinstall into our Mac?

Comment: You need to update your Provisional profile only to select your devices. certificate is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add UDID in Developer account and then download provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

For each provisioning profile you can add or remove a device registered in your account as development device. When you have update the provisioning profile with your device you can download it and double click on it automatically will be imported into xcode. Another way is refresh the account directly from xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to update your certificate. Only need to update your provitioning profile.(make sure this new UDID is checked marked when you update you profile)